# Javascript - Check if Session Cookie still valid

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

We have a 'logged in' cookie which is set when signing into a clients CMS (via asp.net).  Dependant whether the user has asked the site to 'remember me' or not the cookie will either have an expiry time/date set or just be a session cookie.

I need to provide an idle time message on the site via a JS script.

After 5 mins inactivity the script needs to check if the cookie is still active or not.

The inactivity check part of the script works fine - but there doesnt seem to be any way (I can find at least) to check a cookies expiry time / date / type via JS - so i'm not sure how to apprach the cookie check element.   I wondered whether anywone was aware of a method to check whether the cookie is session or dated?  Or Active? I noticed that the cookie itself is removed when expired on windows/ chrome - but retained despite expired on mac?  so not sure a simple read check for the cookie name would be foolproof cross-device.

heres my code so far -

```
 var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); 
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 4) { 
            triggerAlertSortCookie();
        }
    }
    function triggerAlertSortCookie() {
      //Check if AALogin cookie has expired  - show message if so & refresh page.
    }
```

Any advice / suggested code apprach would be great.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

To clarify that I understand what you wanna do: you want to check if the cookie is valid at this moment.
If that's correct, the best way is to implement simple request on server-side that will return boolean response or maybe `200 ok` / `401 unauthorized` status code.

Also, you can just return `401 unauthorized` status code for any request made with not valid cookies, and in js you can refresh, redirect to login page, etc.